# Problema con literales y paso de argumentos en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente función:

```
function abrir(texto) {
var ventana=open('','','top=300,left=300,width=300,height=300) ;
ventana.document.write('<div>'+ texto +'<div>');
}
```

y tengo que pasar unos literales de código HTML. Si hago:

```
var descripcion= '<a onClick="abrir(\'Mi Texto 2\')">Detalles</a>';
```

me funciona correctamente. Se abre una ventana y me muestra el texto, pero si intento pasarle el argumento por referencia, de esta manera:

```
var muestra='Mi Texto 1';   
var descripcion= '<a onClick="abrir(' + muestra +')">Detalles</a>';
```

ni siquiera se abre la ventana.
¿Cual sería la manera correcta de hacerlo?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve]? Si pulsas en [edit] la pregunta y a continuación creas un fragmento ejecutable (Ctrl + M) podrías añadir el código que no te funciona

Comment: Gracias, la próxima vez lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es sencillo, en tu primer ejemplo le proporcionas un valor como texto que será lo que incluirá dentro de el div.

Pero en tu segundo ejemplo únicamente concatenas la variable muestra, y al final js,  no entiende que es lo que le estas pasando, por que no es una función, no es un objeto. Lo que genera es algo como del tipo `abrir(Mi Texto 1)`.

Lo que tienes que hacer en tu caso es agregar como en tu primer ejemplo, comillas adicionales, para que js lo detecte como un string,
`abrir(\'' + muestra +'\')`.

```js
function abrir(texto) {
  document.write('<div>'+ texto +'<div>');
}

var descripcion= '<a onClick="abrir(\'Mi Texto 2\')">Ejemplo 1</a>';

var muestra='Mi Texto 1';   
var descripcion2= '<a onClick="abrir(\'' + muestra +'\')">Ejemplo 2</a>';

abrir(descripcion);

abrir(descripcion2);
```

Comment: Respuesta clara, concisa y rápida. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Poniendo la variable entre ${} en la cadena literal, funcionara sin problemas.

```
var muestra='Mi Texto 1';   
var descripcion=`'<a onClick="abrir(${muestra})">Detalles</a>`;
```

Sacado del link de MSN:
Las plantillas de cadena de caracteres pueden contener marcadores, identificados por el signo de dólar y envueltos en llaves (${expresión}). Las expresiones contenidas en los marcadores, junto con el texto entre ellas, son enviados como argumentos a una función.
De MSN web:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

Comment: Gracias Jonas pero no he conseguido que eso funcione: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-js --> function abrir(texto) { console.log(texto); } var descripcion= '<a onClick="abrir(\'Mi Texto 2\')">Ejemplo 1</a>'; var muestra='Mi Texto 1'; var descripcion2= '<a onClick="abrir(${muestra})">Ejemplo 2</a>'; abrir(descripcion); abrir(descripcion2); <!-- end snippet --> .